# ReadableByteChannel and FileOutputStream only give me 28 bytes of a file downloaded from Soundcloud

Tags: java, soundcloud, fileoutputstream

I'm using `Java`, a `ReadableByteChannel` and `FileOutputStream` to try and pull a wav file from Soundcloud:

```
public static void wavTest() {

    URL website = null;
    try {
        website = new URL("https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/123456789/download?client_id=12lhfdh5k55....283);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = null;
    try {
        rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream("/Users/name/Desktop/test.wav");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The URL works when pasted into a browser and the full track downloads but no matter which tracks I try to download using the code above, the file always has the following properties:

`28 bytes (4 KB on disk)`

Clearly I'm doing something wrong.  Can anybody help me out or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the data that was actually received. Perhaps it is an error response (e.g. it responds with a document containing only `<error>401 - Unauthorized</error>` for [invalid request info](https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/123456789/download)) or some other status response.

Presuming that is the case, perhaps some issue with the IDs or session keys you are sending, or you are forgetting some required HTTP headers in the request (I'm not particularly familiar with the SoundCloud API).

Comment: Thanks for the response but it isn’t a 401 problem.  As I said, I have successfully pulled down the wav from the web and I just noticed that the ‘Where From’ info for the wav I pulled from the web using Google Chrome gives this:

`http://ec-media.soundcloud.com/hrtIXvDAAAuN?ff61182e3c2ecefa438cd0210ad0e38569b9775ddc9e06b3c362ab87309651ead0b4d08ae06316aa9693d4d4b2172c08ae8d00e3b10a3fabf816c9d601&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIA...` 

So, now I’m thinking that the problem is some type of URL redirection issue so I’ll investigate that.

Comment: What is the actual content of the data you receive? Print those 28 bytes out or open the file in a text editor. If it's the first 28 bytes of a wav file, you'll have to keep digging, but if it's an error response, it will give you an immediate clue. It's an easy check. :)

Comment: `<status>302 - Found</status>`  So no error.  Not sure what I should do next!

Comment: OK.  It's a redirection.  I'll check this out:  `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302`  Cheers for the help :-)

Answer (score -1):

I agree with @JasonC that you probably have an error response, but in any case there is nothing that says `transferTo()` transfers the entire contents. It returns a transfer-count. You have to call it in a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the response but it isn’t a 401 problem.  As I said, I have successfully pulled down the wav from the web and I just noticed that the ‘Where From’ info for the wav I pulled from the web using Google Chrome gives this:

`http://ec-media.soundcloud.com/hrtIXvDAAAuN?ff61182e3c2ecefa438cd0210ad0e38569b9775ddc9e06b3c362ab87309651ead0b4d08ae06316aa9693d4d4b2172c08ae8d00e3b10a3fabf816c9d601&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIA...` 

So, now I’m thinking that the problem is some type of URL redirection issue so I’ll investigate that.

Comment: I'll also look at transferTo().  Thanks again